# Does the Church of England omit 'Gloria in Excelsis' in Advent?

Tags: church-of-england, liturgical-calendar

As the Church of England website [explains](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/common-worship/churchs-year/times-and-seasons/lent#mmm117), in the season of **Lent**:

> Liturgical dress is the simplest possible. Churches are kept bare of flowers and decoration. **Gloria in excelsis** is not used. The Fourth Sunday of Lent (Laetareor Refreshment Sunday) was allowed as a day of relief from the rigour of Lent, and the Feast of the Annunciation almost always falls in Lent; these breaks from austerity are the background to the modern observance of Mothering Sunday on the Fourth Sunday of Lent.

**Advent** is a season the church calendar with a [similar](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/common-worship/churchs-year/times-and-seasons/advent#mmm1) quality:

> The characteristic note of **Advent** is therefore expectation, rather than penitence, although the character of the season is easily coloured by an analogy with **Lent**. [...] Church decorations are simple and spare, and purple is the traditional liturgical colour. [...] The Third Sunday of Advent was observed in medieval times as a splash of colour in the restrained atmosphere of Advent (Gaudete or ‘Rose Sunday’), and the last days of Advent were marked by the sequence of Great ‘O’ Antiphons, which continue to inspire modern Advent hymns and meditations.

Is **Gloria in Excelsis** - according to official guidance - omitted by the Church of England in Advent? *I am looking for a specifically Church of England answer, rather than answers from worldwide Anglicanism or Roman Catholicism.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes - omit *Gloria in Excelsis* in Advent also

The [guidance notes for the Holy Communion service](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/common-worship/holy-communion-service) deprecate the inclusion of *Gloria in Excelsis* in Advent:

> **11  The Gloria in Excelsis**
>
> This canticle may be omitted during Advent and Lent, and on weekdays which are not Principal Holy Days or Festivals.

> **29  The Gloria in Excelsis**
>
> If the Gloria in excelsis is not to be used on every occasion, it is appropriately omitted on Sundays in Advent and Lent and on all weekdays that are not Principal Holy Days or Festivals.